# c# object to xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

on object serializing. Is it possible to

1. Convert some characters according to their ASCII values (hexa value)? Like the TM symbol to &#xnum;?
2. Convert the 5 characters below into this:

   ```
   & - &amp,
   ' - &apos;
   " - &quot;
   < - &lt;
   > - &gt;
   ```
3. Lastly, if there's a &amp ;
   value. Is it possible to avoid  '&amp ; amp' ? (no spaces)

Comment: How are you serializing your objects? Most serializers do this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using HTML encode, doesnt work on TM though.It works on the [reserved characters](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) in HTML.

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("&")
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link to get the answer

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316063

Use CDATA in your XML also apply add this header on top
<
xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />